# Express.js request.body not working

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have a simple form for login, the problem is when i press "Submit", the request.body on server side is empty.I saw that bodyParser is a fundamental part but in my case it's declared before the routes, so i think the problem is another. this is my server page **App.js**

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 var err = new Error('Not Found');
 err.status = 404;
 next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 // set locals, only providing error in development
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

 // render the error page
 res.status(err.status || 500);
 res.render('error');
});
app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

this is **index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


function Login(req, res){
 var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/squaredDB', function(err, db)  {
 if(err) throw err;
  db.collection('users').find({email: req.body.email}, function(err, data){
   console.log(req.body);
  });
 });
}


 /* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
 });

 router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Login(req, res);
  res.render('app-home', { title: '' });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

this is my jade template form:

```
form(method="post" action="/")
  label Email
  input(type="text" placeholder="Email")
  label Password
  input(type="password" placeholder="Password")
  input(type="submit" value="login")
```

Comment: I've not used jade but with other templates, the form elements need to have name so you could do `req.body['fieldName']`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `name` attributes for your input fields in your template. Without those the browser won't submit them in the form.

Comment: i'm trying to understand why i didn't used the names ... anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Add a name attribute to your input field it will now be able to access the field via request like **req.body.name**

```
<form action="/", method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```